# Error: Cycle: local.security_groups (expand), aws_security_group.this

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Need help in troubleshooting the cycle error in below configuration. i cannot locate any reference to workbench_service in any of the security groups.
the locals file is as below:

```
locals {
  security_groups = {
    ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod = {
      ingress = {
        WCC_user_redirect = {
          description = "Wcc Internal users connect to ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod"
          type        = "ingress"
          port        = 8080
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = var.workstation_subnets
        }
        WCC_workspaces_redirect = {
          description = "Workspaces users connect to ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod"
          port        = 8080
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = var.workspace_subnets
        }
      }
      egress = {
        all = {
          description = "Traffic to workbench service"
          type        = "egress"
          port        = 8080
          protocol    = "tcp"
          //cidr_blocks = ["10.103.8.0/24"]
          source_security_group_rule = aws_security_group.this["workbench_service"].id
        }
      }
    }
workbench_service = {
      ingress = {
        from_ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod = {
          description = "Traffic from ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod"
          type        = "ingress"
          port        = 8080
          protocol    = "tcp"
          //source_security_group = aws_security_group.this["ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod"].id
          cidr_blocks = ["10.103.8.0/24"]
        }
      }
      egress = {
        all = {
          type        = "egress"
          port        = 0
          protocol    = "-1"
          protocl     = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = ["10.103.8.0/24"]
        }
        https = {
          description = "HTTPS traffic from ecs services"
          type        = "egress"
          port        = 443
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }
         efs = {
          description           = "workbench to efs mount points"
          type                  = "egress"
          port                  = 2049
          protocol              = "tcp"
          //source_security_group = aws_security_group.this["efs_mount_sg"].id
          cidr_blocks = ["10.103.8.0/24"]
        }
      }
    }
  }


  security_group_rules_flat = flatten([
    for rule_key, rule_value in local.security_groups : [
      for rule_type_key, rule_type_attr in rule_value : [
        for rule, rule_attr in rule_type_attr : {
          security_group            = rule_key
          protocol                  = rule_attr.protocol
          port                      = try(rule_attr.port, null)
          from_port                 = try(rule_attr.from_port, null)
          to_port                   = try(rule_attr.to_port, null)
          type                      = rule_type_key
          name                      = rule
          description               = try(rule_attr.description, null)
          cidr_blocks               = try(rule_attr.cidr_blocks, null)
          source_security_group_key = try(rule_attr.source_security_group_key, null)
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])
  security_group_rules = { for rule in local.security_group_rules_flat : "${rule.security_group}.${rule.type}.${rule.name}" => rule }
}
```

the security groups are defined in sg.tf file as below:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  for_each = local.security_groups

  name        = "${var.cluster_name}/${each.key}"
  description = "Security group for ${var.cluster_name}/${each.key}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id_prod
  tags        = merge(var.tags, { Name = "${var.cluster_name}/${each.key}" })
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this" {
  for_each = local.security_group_rules

  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.this[each.value.security_group].id
  description              = try(each.value.description, null)
  type                     = each.value.type
  from_port                = coalesce(each.value.port, each.value.from_port)
  to_port                  = coalesce(each.value.port, each.value.to_port)
  protocol                 = each.value.protocol
  cidr_blocks              = try(each.value.cidr_blocks, null)
  source_security_group_id = try(coalesce(each.value.source_security_group_id, aws_security_group.this[each.value.source_security_group_key].id), null)
}
```

The terraform validate is generating below error as mentioned in the subject:

**Error: Cycle: aws_security_group.this, local.security_groups (expand)**

Comment: thanks Matt for pointing it out, I made the changes and it is getting validated now; but while applying the configuration it seems like it cannot find the reference security group id: ``Error: One of ['cidr_blocks', 'ipv6_cidr_blocks', 'self', 'source_security_group_id', 'prefix_list_ids'] must be set to create an AWS Security Group Rule
│
│   with aws_security_group_rule.this["ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod.egress.all"],
│   on r_sg.tf line 12, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this":
│   12: resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this" {``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the dependency cycle is because your `aws_security_group.this` depends on `local.security_groups`, and your nested `local.security_groups.ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod.egress.all.source_security_group_rule` causes a dependency on `aws_security_group.this`. You unfortunately cannot avoid this by changing to `for_each = toset(keys(local.security_groups))`.

You will need to fix this by decoupling the security group names from the `local.security_groups` with the security group rules from the `local.security_groups`. The names will need to be a `set` or a `list` converted to `set`, and the security group rules can remain in the structure you have above. For example:

```
locals {
  security_group_names = toset(["ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod", "workbench_service"])
}
```

and then:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "this" {
  for_each = local.security_group_names
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks Matt for pointing it out, I made the changes and it is getting validated now; but while applying the configuration it seems like it cannot find the reference security group id: `Error: One of ['cidr_blocks', 'ipv6_cidr_blocks', 'self', 'source_security_group_id', 'prefix_list_ids'] must be set to create an AWS Security Group Rule │ │   with aws_security_group_rule.this["ALB_Internal_rules_workbench_prod.egress.all"], │   on r_sg.tf line 12, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this": │   12: resource "aws_security_group_rule" "this" {`

Comment: @Zuntoo That is a different question compared to the original one.

Comment: Was not getting the error before executing the code, i presume the suggested changes generated the error, appreciate if you can answer Marko

Comment: @Zuntoo That is indeed a different question. Now that I solved your cyclical dependency, Terraform is throwing the next error for a different issue in your code.